# Germany Work visa dates

Tags: germany, indian-citizens

I am presently in India and travelling to  Germany (dates in the application May 18th to October 16th) it is for 5 months. But since I have not got my visa yet, will there be still 5 months validity in my visa or will I lose some days.

What if I get Visa after two weeks? 
Will the dates on visa automatically start from the date they put it on passport or will they still stick to the original dates in my application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based on the regulations stated in the **Visumhandbuch** (July 2018)
(Visa Guidlines for the issuing of National Visa's)

- General conditions for the issuing of a national visa
  Chapter V

(1) Working visa's are (in general) to be approved by the local German Foreigners office

- where the date is then set, based on application

(2) States that the Foreigner must report to the Foreigners office **before** the visa expires

---

Based on these regulations it would seem that:

- the consulate cannot change a date approved by the Foreigners office
- any desired extension must be applied for at the Foreigners Office

---

Link where the Visumhandbuch (in German) can be found:

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/einreiseundaufenthalt/visa/207794

This page also states:

- A Visa, that the Foreigners Office must approve, may take up to **three months**
- the application should be made in a **timely manor**

Comment: Thank you for your reply